# Magento 1.7: Create invoice from an order OK, but the transaction is missing

Tags: php, magento

I'm completely lost at this moment.
I want to generate an invoice and a transaction for a given order.

here's the relevant part of the code:

```
try {
  if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
  }

  $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

  if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
  }
  $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
  $invoice->register();
  $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
        ->addObject($invoice)
        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

  $transactionSave->save();
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
  print_r($e);
}
```

Everything works fine without errors and/or warnings, but the result is that I can clearly see the generated invoice in the `Sales -> Orders -> #myorder -> Invoices` tab, but the `Transactions` tab shows "`No records found.`".

Is there something else I have to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction data is stored in `sales_payment_transaction`

```
sales_payment_transaction 
  website_magento.sales_payment_transaction has 24126 records
                       Field Type           Null Key Default  Extra Comment
            `transaction_id` int(10) unsign   NO PRI ┈   auto_increment  Transaction Id 
                 `parent_id` int(10) unsign  yes MUL ┈   ┈   Parent Id 
                  `order_id` int(10) unsign   NO MUL ┈   ┈   Order Id 
                `payment_id` int(10) unsign   NO MUL ┈   ┈   Payment Id 
                    `txn_id` varchar(100)    yes     ┈   ┈   Txn Id 
             `parent_txn_id` varchar(100)    yes     ┈   ┈   Parent Txn Id 
                  `txn_type` varchar(15)     yes     ┈   ┈   Txn Type 
                 `is_closed` smallint(5) un   NO     1  ┈   Is Closed 
    `additional_information` blob            yes     ┈   ┈   Additional Information 
                `created_at` timestamp       yes     ┈   ┈   Created At
```

The output above is from development code I wrote to better understand Magento tables. I have a form that takes a search string and replies with all `field names` and `tables` with that search string in their names. [I share my db helper functions with a Gist here](https://gist.github.com/cacycleworks/546137adc92dc00c0f5390032bf07883); I make a `.php` page just for me to run tests like this.

Actual output of helper function below:
[image: Visual of output from my helper function(s)]